# Transform java lambda expression to 1.6 version

Tags: java, lambda

I have a code made with java 1.8 and i'd like to transform it to make it work with 1.6.

This code is the following one:

```
private void handleCanNotConnect(Throwable cause) {
    isConnected = false;
    fireAll(l -> l.connectionFailed(cause));
}

private void fireAll(Consumer<MyListener> action){
    action.accept(listener);
}
```

How i should transform it?

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back before lambda functions, we would instantiate anonymous classes to implement interfaces on the fly.

Here is an interface, since `Consumer<MyListener>` isn't available:

```
public interface MyConsumer {
    public void accept(MyListener l);
}
```

Then you can use:

```
private void handleCanNotConnect(final Throwable cause) {
    isConnected = false;
    fireAll(new MyConsumer() {
        @Override
        public void accept(MyListener l) {
            l.connectionFailed(cause);
        }
    });
}

private void fireAll(MyConsumer action){
    action.accept(listener);
}
```

Note that the `cause` is marked as `final`.

Comment: `Consumer` is since 1.8, isn't it?

Comment: @StefanWarminski Oh right. There's that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks